# How to get usable size screen size in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, screen, android-screen-support

So I want to make an app compatible with multiple screen sizes, however the positioning of some buttons is done programmatically and it has to align with the background (timetable app, task aligned with proper day, start time and end time on a grid display). Hence, I need to get the screen dimensions.

Currently I'm testing this in Nokia 8.1 with height 2246px and width 1080px, however what I need is the actual usable height not the total height (minus the bar at the top and the bottom). After manually testing the usable height it seems to be 1887px, but I have not found a way to retrieve this number.

I tried these codes so far:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
int displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels; //2246px
int displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels; //1080px
```

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels; //2034px
int displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels; //1080px
```

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) mainActivity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int height = size.y; //2034px
int width = size.x; //1080px
```

I thought maybe navigation bar is the problem

```
Resources resources = mainContext.getResources();
int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
int navigation_bar_height = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId); //126px
```

2034 - 126 = 1908px != 1887px (which is close but still to big, it goes off screen)

Furthermore, when I tried to make a new hardware profile with the phone dimensions (2246 x 1080), using 1887px goes off screen on the xml Design display, even though it shows up exactly right on my phone...

So yeah I'm lost, no idea how to get the real size or why the profile doesn't match. Please help.

Comment: You need to subtract status bar height by int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android"); ...